# How refined sugar intake affect the exercise results?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, burn-fat, sugar

I am doing regular exercise like jogging & stretching from last 3 month to lose extra weight my BMI is 28/29 and lose 2 Kg, I am not following any diet plan.

One of friend suggest me to stop eating refined sugar, It affect the exercise results. During my daily routine I drink 2-3 cup of coffee/tea which includes sugar, should I stop eating sugar or sugary product completely and follow a strict diet plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is excessive calorie intake that results in weight gain, not sugar.

- Refined or any other sugar and other carbohydrates = 4 Cal/g
- Protein = 4 Cal/g
- Fat = 9 Cal/g
- Alcohol = 7 Cal/g
- *Source: [ucla.edu](http://www.dining.ucla.edu/housing_site/dining/SNAC_pdf/CaloriesCount.pdf)*

> Among free living people involving ad libitum diets, intake of free
>   sugars or sugar sweetened beverages is a determinant of body weight.
>   The change in body fatness that occurs with modifying intakes seems to
>   be mediated via changes in energy intakes, since *isoenergetic exchange
>   of sugars with other carbohydrates was not associated with weight
>   change* ([BMJ, 2013](https://www.bmj.com/content/346/bmj.e7492)).

BUT...

> There are epidemiological data, plausible mechanisms and clinical data
>   from diet intervention studies that provide strong support for a
>   direct causal/contributory role of sugar in the epidemics of metabolic
>   disease, and for an *indirect causal/contributory role mediated by
>   sugar consumption promoting body weight and fat gain* ([Critical Reviews in Clinical Laboratory Sciences, 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4822166/)).

SO...

If sweetness tempts you to eat more than you want, it's a good tactic to avoid foods sweetened with sugar or other sweeteners. Stopping drinking sugar-sweetened beverages (soda, fruit juice...) can be a good start.

Comment: Emphasis on the last paragraph. I believe that most of our fat increases are directly from sugar (despite fat having higher calories per gram) simply because it's super easy to over eat when sugar is involved. And excess sugar gets converted into fat in the body. Drinking calories is an easy way to intake too many calories because drinks don't fill us up like food so it doesn't seem like we just took up calories when in fact we did.